# Spring Data Mongo test field

Tags: spring, mongodb, criteria

I'm using Spring Data Mongo and a Mongo DB;

In a collection, docs have a field, let's say containing an integer and we call it myInt.

I want to retrieve all docs having myInt between 2 dynamic ints like :

`myInt - dynInt1 < myInt < myInt + dynInt2`

I need to use the field myInt in requests, I can pre-calculate it in java to use it in creterias.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method in your SpringData interface:

```
    YourEntity findByMyIntLessThanAndMyIntGreaterThan(int min, int max);
```

Next, perform a find call, take myInt value and perform a second call with the two values:

```
    int myInt = myRepository.findByXXXX().getMyInt();
    int min = myInt - dynInt1;
    int max = myInt + dynInt2;
    myRepository.findByMyIntLessThanAndMyIntGreaterThan(min, max);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it can be done in SpringData as follows:

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("field").gt(value1).lt(value2));
```

Comment: but how can I do something like query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("field").gt("field" - value1).lt("field" + value2));

Answer (score -1):

Use gte(greater than and equalto) and lte(less than and equalto) if you want to include dynamic int values also in your criteria.

Comment: but how can I do something like query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("field").gt("field" - value1).lt("field" + value2));